# AJAX Valums upload (HTML5 uploader using drag and drop) - possible to make files queue?

Tags: ajax, file-upload

Anyone else use Valums Ajax upload?

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

I was wondering if anyone has a solution to make the files queue and go one by one instead of all files at once.

Answer (score 2):

Set max connections to 1:

"**maxConnections: 1**"